# Cyber Security skills development advice

Tags: vulnerability, attack-prevention, attack-vector

I'm looking to shift my job / skillset over to the cyber security field. I'm currently in the script kiddy stages of my knowledge and wanted to move past this and locate/identify vulnerabilities without having to rely on scripts.

Does anyone know of any good courses / websites / any pointers for me to start developing these skills? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The subreddit r/asknetsec is a about „cyber“ career and learning advice, and will help you.

Doing CTFs and reading the „solutions“ (https://ctftime.org) is immensely valuable. Start no higher than https://picoctf.org or you will be overwhelmed.

Harder CTFs will cover finding & exploiting new vulnerabilities. This is a good entry point: https://exploit.education

For real-world challenges I recommend https://www.hackthebox.com .

To get started, watch videos where other people solve these challenges (e.g. https://m.youtube.com/channel/UC0ZTPkdxlAKf-V33tqXwi3Q )

You will not get around learning the fundamentals is you don’t cover them already: Basic Computer Science, basic networking, and programming (python and C are useful. To learn binary exploitation, you MUST know C and assembly language first).

Web hacking is its own discipline. „The tangled web“ is a great book.

Have fun!